# How to register an ItemBlock in Minecraft Forge?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

So I'm trying to make a custom block in my mod. I tried to register it, but found out that the API has changed and I had no idea how to register my block. After some research, I found out that you need to register the Block AND the ItemBlock. So I tried making an ItemBlock out of my Block using this code:

```
public ItemBlock itemBlock = new ItemBlock(this);
```

This code is inside my Block class. Then I tried registering the block:

```
event.getRegistry().register(new myBlockInMyMod());
event.getRegistry().register(new myBlockInMyMod().itemBlock);
```

I get this error code on IntelliJ:

```
register (net.minecraft.block.Block) in IForgeRegistry cannot be applied to net.minecraft.item.ItemBlock
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? Because the register method doesn't seem to accept ItemBlocks :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, you have two problems:

1. That's not how you get an item block (or at least, what you're doing is a bad idea)
2. You need to register the ItemBlock in the `Registry.Register<Item>` event, not the `Register<Block>` event, as they are different registries.

The first problem is easy to fix:

```
new ItemBlock(block_reference_variable)
```

However, you don't currently have a reference to your block. You instantiate it and shove it directly into the registry, never holding onto a reference to refer to later.  Most people create [static fields in their main mod class](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/master/src/main/java/com/draco18s/ores/OresBase.java#L95-L102).

You can, if you want, store a reference to the ItemBlock as you are, but when you create a *new instance* of your block, that ItemBlock has no bearing on the block you registered. They're different objects.  You *must* store a reference to your block somewhere.

The second problem requires you write a *second* event handler method, only you change `<Block>` to `<Item>`: The `Blocks.REGISTERY` cannot accept `Items`, you need to wait for the `Items.REGISTRY` to fire its registration event.

Comment: Will try this out after school